# Build an array from array of hashes

Tags: ruby

I have two Arrays with hashes that looks like below

```
array_1 = [{"id": "1", "value": "Option_A", default_weight: "50"}, {"id": "2", "value": "Option_B", default_weight: "75"}]

array_2 = [{"id": "2", "value": "Option_B", custom_weight: "35"}]
```

Now I'm trying build an array which will contain only weights based on the following condition

Pick the `default_weight` of the object from `array_1` if that doesn't exist in `array_2`. If it exists in `array_2`, pick `custom_weight`

The expected output will be `[50.0, 35.0]`

**My failed attempt:**

```
new_array = []
array_1.each do |array_1_item|
  array_2.map {|array_2_item| array_1_item["value"] == array_2_item["value"] ? new_array << array_2_item["custom_weight"].to_f : new_array << array_1_item[:default_weight].to_f}
end
```

I get `[50.0, 50.0, 35.0, 75.0]`

Any help is much appreciated, TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try turning `array_2` into a hash first:

```rb
custom_weights = {}
array_2.each { |item| custom_weights[item[:value]] = item[:custom_weight] }
```

Then you can do:

```rb
array_1.map { |item| (custom_weights[item[:value]] || item[:default_weight]).to_f }
 => [50.0, 35.0]
```